# Unable to check whether the location specified is on CFS

Tags: oracle-12c

I have googled this error message and it says:

> **INS-30014**: Unable to check whether the location specified is on CFS
>   **Cause**: The location specified might not have the required permissions.
>   **Action**: Provide a location which has the appropriate required permissions.

But I am already the administrator and run the installation file as administrator. Any idea? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Neither did "Security-Settings" work nor was the "NAT NIC" relevant for my configuration.
I just disconnected my machine from the internet (only WLAN -> flight mode) for that single step and was able to finish the installation, 19c in my case (Win 10 Pro, installation directly on the maschine but Docker was running in Hyper-V, what might have caused the problem in the first place).

Comment: @AndreasJ please write this comment as an answer and ping me to up-vote because this was exactly the issue I was facing. Thanks!

Comment: I just disconnected mt network adapter and I could pass this step

Answer (score 9):

There are many suggestions how to solve this problems floating around (and many are undoubetly in their way correct)

In my case, neither did the change of "Security-Settings" work nor was the "NAT NIC" relevant for my configuration.

**Solution (in my case):**
I just disconnected my machine from the internet (I had only WLAN -> set to flight mode) *only for that single step* in the procedure (you have to re-connect in the following step or the install will fail)
and was able to finish the installation, Oracle 19c in my case (on Win 10 Pro, installation directly on the machine. Docker was running in Hyper-V, what might have caused the problem in the first place).

Hope others can profit from this

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: I had Docker Desktop running in the background so I quit that and disabled WiFi by toggling on Airplane mode. The first time I retried I got the same error, but after waiting a few more seconds and trying again it worked. [Windows 10 Pro, Oracle 19c]

Comment: Then, you have to connect back to the internet during the install or it could fail on Oracle Net Configuration Assistant

Comment: Surprisingly, this works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Go to the folder properties, indicated in the path of "Oracle base". go to security tab, click edit button (not the advance), click "Authenticated Users", check the "Full Control" box in ALLOW. click okay and continue your installation.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this on a VM with NAT NIC. Installer was pulling in DNS suffix from NIC and messing up DNS name of my server on install. Disabling NAT NIC allowed to me to install and then I re-enabled after install and it was fine. Not related to permissions at all.

Comment: had 2 NICs both NAT. disabled both, got to the next screen.

Answer (score 2):

Your server's NetBIOS name is too long. Change it shorter (under 15 chars) and retry.

Comment: Is there any way you can elaborate on this? I can't see how you got that information from this post. I'm sure it would help the next person along too if you were able to explain how to easily detect this. Most of the time Windows won't let you set a name too long for NetBIOS.

Comment: Although this has been downvoted, +1 from me because it saved our day.  We had a computer name longer than 15 chars and received the same exact error.

Comment: This was the one that solved the issue for me, changed machine's hostname to something under 15 chars, restarted and installation magically worked. Perhaps it's the same thing affected by "disabling network". Oracle installer is not very nice managing exceptions... (lot better than it was on 8i, though)

Comment: This solved my problem as well