# Install Oracle Database 12c Error unable to check whether the location specified is on CFS

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, installation

[image: **enter image description here**]ps://i.stack.imgur.com/0DX0d.png

I am trying to install the Oracle database 12c on the Windows 10 Laptop.

Have tried disk C and disk E, got the same error.

And I tried to change the file properties, change the security to allow the full control.. And still got the same error message.

Anyone could help me with this? Thank you!!!!

Comment: Your screen differs from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175938/unable-to-check-whether-the-location-specified-is-on-cfs, where "file system" is selected. Strange, your image is gone.

Answer (score 0):

there is two solutions for this:
1- install Oracle as administrator
2- create a folder in C or E drive then right click it, go to security tab, and change permission for the user (grant him owner access on that folder)

Answer (score -1):

Go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and edit the host file.
Add your ip at the end of the file like `172.XX.XXX.1 oracle`